# ValueError: too many values to unpack matplotlib errorbar

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a errorbar:

```
plt.errorbar(np.array(x_axis), np.array(y_axis), yerr=(np.array(y_bot), np.array(y_top)), linestyle='None', marker='^')
```

But it throws an error :

```
plt.errorbar(np.array(x_axis), np.array(y_axis), yerr=(np.array(y_bot), np.array(y_top)), linestyle='None', marker='^')


File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2747, in errorbar
    errorevery=errorevery, capthick=capthick, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 2792, in errorbar
    barcols.append(self.vlines(xo, lo, uo, **lines_kw))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1067, in vlines
    for thisx, (thisymin, thisymax) in zip(x, Y)]
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

x_axis, y_axis, y_bot, x_bot are 1D array of length 4.

Comment: your code works fine for me, maybe you should double check the shape of your arrays. Incidentally, if your arrays are already numpy arrays, why are you trying to convert them to numpy array again?

Comment: Are you sure `y_axis`, `y_bot` and `y_top` have the same length ?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Yes they are of same length

Comment: Could you include some example arrays that trigger the issue ?

Answer (score 3):

The following works fine for me:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_axis = range(4)
y_axis = range(4)
y_bot = range(4)
y_top = range(4)
plt.errorbar(np.array(x_axis), np.array(y_axis), yerr=(np.array(y_bot), np.array(y_top)), linestyle='None', marker='^')
```

You way want to verify your arrays